# disable mod_proxy for subdirectory (apache)

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-proxy

I have apache with one folder used for reverse proxy:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ...
 ProxyPass /site http://server.local:8989/site
 ProxyPassReverse /site http://server.local:8989/site
</VirtualHost *:80>
```

How can I disable proxy for url's /site/IMAGES/* ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add *before* the first `ProxyPass`:

```
ProxyPass /site/IMAGES/ !
```

See the [mod_proxy docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) for the full details.

Comment: No work for me on centos7.

Answer (score 3):

It wouldn't have been available at the time you asked this question, but if you're using Apache HTTPD 2.4 or later, then [as described in the docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) you could do it with two location blocks:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ...
  <Location /site>
    ProxyPass        http://server.local:8989/site
    ProxyPassReverse http://server.local:8989/site
  </Location>
  <Location /site/IMAGES>
    ProxyPass "!"
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Location blocks are interpreted in order, so you need to put the no-proxy one after the proxy one. Alternately, if you want to keep the proxy directives at the vhost level, the answer given by fission works just fine!

Comment: For multiple exclusions, regular expressions can also be used, with the addition of the `~` character. For example: `<Location ~ "/(extra|special)/data">`

Answer (score 0):

This wasn't enough for my situation.
ProxyPass /site/IMAGES/ ! 
I wanted to exclude some paths and not only one like that case, I searched online and all are talking about t=something like this, 
ProxyPass /site/IMAGES/ ! 
This only valid when you want to exclude only one path, works great! but I wanted to exclude some paths and not only one, so I tried to do it like this, 
ProxyPass /site/IMAGES/ !
ProxyPass /site-web/ !
Not working also, it's valid to bypass only one path at a time.
So Thanks Gagravarr, I could do what I need using Location with Apache and I could ProxyPass exclude some paths like,
`<Location "/admin">
ProxyPass "!"
</Location>
<Location "/mail">
ProxyPass "!"
</Location>
<Location "/html">
ProxyPass "!"
</Location>
<Location "/shared">
ProxyPass "!"
</Location>
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://193.168.1.3/
ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.3/`
I think this may help somebody on my situation.